# How can I invite a friend to a server I am on in Battlelog for Battlefield 4 on PC?

Tags: battlefield-4, battlelog

How can I invite a friend to a server I am on in Battlelog in Battlefield 4 on PC?

I have seen this:

> Hint: Did you know you can invite friends to Servers? Drag a friend
>   from the Com Center to a Drop Zone to invite him or her to the server.

What do they mean by drop zone?

*A screenshot here would be very beneficial*

Comment: Is this PC or XBOX/PS3?

Comment: Well on Xbox all you have to do is invite them through Xbox Live friends list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite easy as it seems.

1. You must already be in a server at the moment. You need to have the blue bar at the bottom as shown in Battlelog.

[image: Screenshot of Battlelog]

2. Then click and drag your friend to the blue bar and a new opening will appear and drop him into this. [image: http://i.imgur.com/UA5bXpm.jpg]

Now your friend is invited. Works on both consoles and PC.